# known_hosts domain can switch keys

Tags: ssh, solaris

Solaris systems, local system has known_hosts with key automatically added.  Target systems have authorized_keys2.

Target system is one of two servers configured active-passive.  Switch back and forth monthly (or failover).  Target servers have two different hostnames on the same domain.  Two different IP addresses.

VIP configuration is set with one virtual host name so that it will always land on the active server of the pair.  Let's say bar.  Remote user foo.

Source system originates scp or ssh connection to the VIP domain.
ssh foo@bar.subdom.dom.com, or just ssh@foo.bar

Once the key is stored in the known_hosts, all is fine for the month, but when it changes to the opposite node, it fails with:

WARNING:  REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED

blah blah

RSA Host key for dokes has changed and you have requested strict checking

Suggestions to have 2 different keys allowable for one VIP server name?

Thanks
JimR

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the host keys from one machine to the other to get rid of the message. that is what you sometimes do when serving ssh behind a loadbalancer as well.

i do not know about solaris, but the keys might be located at /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key and /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub or somewhere similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can have *two entries* in known_hosts with the same VIP address, but different keys.  I manually edited known_hosts to add the 2nd key.

I installed that today, and it works on the first node.  I will confirm next month with the automated switchover that it continues to work on the opposite node.

JimR